# Warning: Three libnl* v.3.2.21-1ubuntu1, update from January 29th broke my network manager

Tags: networking

I've updated my PC last night (January 29th) with only 3 updates available, libnl-3-200, libnl-genl-3-200 and libnl-route-3-200, all version 3.2.21-1ubuntu1, and after reboot my network manager was gone.

Reinstalling network manager nor restarting the demon manually did not helped.

I managed to download previous Trusty versions of those packages (3.2.21-1) and downgrade them back with dpkg. After reboot things went back to normal.

Cheers.

Comment: I've got the same issue, I'm I complete noob though when it comes to this and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Same thing, same fix. Not that they are only in trusty-proposed, so if you haven't turned those on you won't get a problem.

Comment: @Feyn:
Download libnl-3-200 from here: http://goo.gl/ncsjPn
Download libnl-genl-3-200 from here: http://goo.gl/t0jD2j
Download libnl-route-3-200 from here: http://goo.gl/8lZZDS
Then put them is the same folder (with no other debs) and run:
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
Reboot and it should be fixed. Mind you that afterwards you should lock their version in Synaptic so that they won't be picked up again for an update.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as a duplicate to another question, since I've seen several of these and don't want loads floating around. I've expanded on your instructions there.

Comment: OK, so Lewis Goddard take my answer and post it as it's own, without mentioning me and then he closed my post as duplicate although it was the first post + solution to this problem?

WTF? Good bye ElementaryOS StackExchange.