# No WIFI access after update

Tags: wifi, updates

I've got here a notebook running elementary OS. There's been an update some days ago that apparently disabled its WIFI completely - it doesn't show any networks and I can't connect to anything.

I've already done the procedure described [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4178/warning-three-libnl-v-3-2-21-1ubuntu1-update-from-january-29th-broke-my-netwo), downgraded the packages libnl-3-200, libnl-genl-3-200 and libnl-route-3-200 and restarted. Yet it still won't work, it seems like something else causes the problem. I can get a connection via cable but this cannot be a permanent solution. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it: wifi adapter is a Broadcom BCM4313. First I disabled it in Software Center -> Edit -> Software Sources -> Additional Drivers. Then I used

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

to get rid of the driver. And

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

to install a new one. After a reboot it worked again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I had the same problem and ran your commands on elementary os. The wifi is working perfectly after a reboot !

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  Thank you very much.